# How is this parsed by the Javascript lexer? (Closures-pattern without parens)

Tags: javascript

I've noticed this pattern of wrapping closures in parens `()`

```
(function () {
  var foo = 1;
  return function () {return foo}
}())
```

It raises the question, how is this supposed to be parsed:

```
function () {
  var foo = 1;
  return function () {return foo}
}()
```

Comment: it doesn't beg the question, it raises the question

Comment: That's not necessarily a closure, merely an anonymous function.

Comment: I assume you just omitted the left hand side? Both expressions are invalid if you don't assign them to a variable.

Comment: @Felix, how is the first expression invalid? It returns `function () {return foo}`

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses around the function are necessary, because when omitted, the compiler assumes it is a Function Statement.

Function statements are not invocable.

Comment: @Felix: Not exactly the same example, is it? I think you're assuming useage that Evan maybe is not.

Comment: @two7s_clash: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Felix, both of the above functions parse and are valid (although maybe useless) if you assign them to a variable. Only the first is valid if you don't. That's what my answer is based on.

Comment: @two7s_clash: I see. I ran the first code and I got a syntax error, but now not anymore. I guess I did something wrong. NVM then. *But* I think it is better to write that in the first case, it is treated as *function expression* and in the second case as *function declaration*. Declarations need names.

Comment: @Felix, I agree. As I said, the second is treated as a function declaration aka function statement. But perhaps I was being too literal in my answer and your explanations are probably more helpful to the asker here.